# Class derived from ICommand with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

I have the following property:

```
public ICommand ApplySelectedSearchResultCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(ApplySelectedSearchResult, IsSearchResultSelected); } }
```

The class `RelayCommand` is a class from a MVVM-mini-"framework" which is derived from `ICommand`:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public RelayCommand(Action execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<Boolean> canExecute)
    {

        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
}
```

However my method `ApplySelectedSearchResult` which was without parameters so far has changed and contains to parameters now:

```
protected abstract void ApplySelectedSearchResult(Model primaryModel, Model secondaryModel);
```

How to change my property?

Comment: Where should these `Model` arguments come from?

Comment: @CharlesMager I was about to write the same :)

Comment: Every viewModel has a primaryModel (Type `Model`) and secondaryModel (Type `Model`).

Comment: You mean you have the properties in the same class? If yes, why do you need parameters? Why can't you directly use the properties inside the method?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, as you suggest, the view model has these models then you can either create a parameterless method that provides the arguments:

```
private void ApplySelectedSearchResult()
{
    ApplySelectedSearchResult(primary, secondary);
}
```

Or inline this as an action delegate:

```
new RelayCommand(() => ApplySelectedSearchResult(primary, secondary), IsSearchResultSelected);
```